# Preparing basemaps for offline use?

Tags: arcgis-online, basemap, offline, arcgis-explorer

we have an offine application of ArcGIS Explorer (in Germany) and we have to have the base map as well. I have searched About the possible solution and saw the ESRI  solution for that via creating tile packages in ArcGIS Pro ([https://community.esri.com/groups/survey123/blog/2016/01/06/prepare-basemaps-for-offline-use)](https://community.esri.com/groups/survey123/blog/2016/01/06/prepare-basemaps-for-offline-use) or (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-map-tile-package.htm). We have tried it for Topographic Map and even OSM Data but None of them work and we receive error.

We use ArcGIS 10.5 and we have Enterprise lisense in the Company. I have read other Questions in this Topic in the Group too they were not practical for our case.

What could be the possible Problem?

[image]

Comment: We had to reproject the data to WGS 1984 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere)  for this to work. Your Extents look like a different projection

Answer (score 2):

If you are pointing to the esri basemap layers with no "Export" in the title this will not work. I would recommend checking out this esri labs sample application that will support export on the esri tile layers that support this capability. https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/apps/data-management/introducing-tile-package-kreator-esri-labs/

Comment: that means that there is no possibility to use ArcMAP or ArcGIS Pro? what About ArcGIS for Server?

Comment: If the cached map service exists on your server you can enable export tile cache and do it through the REST endpoint https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/export-tiles-map-service-.htm. You could also use Collector to generate the tile package and connect the device to your computer to and copy the tpk off to share with your coworkers and use in other apps.